# PHPExcel insert new blank row after the last row in the sheet

Tags: phpexcel

How can I insert new blank row? ( for separating my rows ) . 
My code is:

```
 $num_rows = $xls->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
 //there need to insert a blank new row 
 $sheet->fromArray($header,null, "A".($num_rows + 1));
```

How can I solve this problem? Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blank row after the last row in the sheet? Why? Blank rows at the end of  worksheet just take up memory.

But if you want to write data to cells beyond the end of the spreadsheet, then just do so....

```
$num_rows = $xls->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
// Add 2 instead of 1
$sheet->fromArray($header,null, "A".($num_rows + 2));
```

Comment: No, I mean that I want to insert a blank row for separating next row in my sheet. So on first row I print some text , then I want to insert blank row and than I want to print my data. Or maybe I can do margin-top? Or what?

Comment: No, just do what I said..... add 2 to `$num_rows` instead of 1.... that will insert the new data 2 rows below the current end row, not on the next row

Comment: Oh, it was a very simple solution. Thanks!